# Mysql Error: duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

In the back office of Prestashop shop I am currently getting an error every time I try to update or add a product. 
The error is below.

```
Duplicate entry '31-17998' for key 'PRIMARY'

ALTER TABLE `ps_search_index` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_word`, `id_product`)
```

Does anybody knows what is causing this and how to resolve it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you customized the Prestashop code (third party extensions, your own changes)? If not, you should report this at [the Prestashop Issue Tracker](http://forge.prestashop.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa) instead of here.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is caused by re-indexing the search and refreshing that page in back office many times? My Prestashop version is 1.4.4.1 so maybe if I replace search file with the latest one, that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this error, by replacing Search.php class with the latest version (from Prestashop version 1.4.8.2, currently using 1.4.4.1), also I had to copy a new function from Tools.php called replaceAccentedChars, otherwise would give me an error. I will report to Prestashop issue tracker next time @DCoder.